# How to control width of Visual composer plugin full width sections

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using visual composer plug-in , I have an issue related to full width sections of visual composer. In my site I am using fixed sidebar menu, but the visual composer full width sections hides behind the sidebar. Is there any method to control full width sections width(I am using stretch row with content option of row) 
You can also check this screen shot:: https://s.nimbus.everhelper.me/share/1573733/m9lwy8k7tm4p4c3qtz3y

My structure is like:

```
<body>
<div class="site-menu">
<!-- contains sidebar menu code -->
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
<!-- contains site content -->
</div>
</body>
```

I assigned a 60px width to my site menu and , added margin-left to "wrapper". I works totally fine, there is only a problem with visual composer full width section, they goes bind the sidebar menu.

Comment: Can you able to share website link or jsfiddle. So that we can able to check the issue and provide solutions faster?

Comment: Actually I cannot share my site link for now, but I will try to give you jsfiddle link here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Visual Composer Website Builder (not WPBakery Page Builder), then this is possible. You have to add class - 'vce-full-width-custom-container' to your wrapper like this -

```
<body>
<div class="site-menu">
<!-- contains sidebar menu code -->
</div>
<div class="wrapper vce-full-width-custom-container">
<!-- contains site content -->
</div>
</body>
```

So full width row will be related now to this wrapper instead of body.

Comment: Hi, I am using page builder here. And still having the same issue.